# NullPointerException in Tree?

Tags: java, tree, binary-tree, nodes

```
public class Node {

  int value;
  List<Node> childNodes;

  Node(int x) {
    value = x;
  }
}
```

Above is the definition of the tree node and we have a tree.

```
Node root = new Node(0);
Node n1 = new Node(1);
root.childNodes.add(n1);  Line 1
```

This is how I construct the initial tree structure in main, however, I got a nunllpointerexception in line 1. Anybody knows the reason?

Comment: I don't think that it is duplicate, it is in a specific condition.

Comment: when you declare `List<Node> childNodes;` as a property, you do not initialize the generic List (the list is a generic interface, not a class; it's null as long as you do not initialize it). E.g. if you add into your constructor `childnodes = new ArrayList<>();` or if you declare the property as `List<Node> childNodes = new Arraylist<>();`, it won't throw an exception.

Comment: @sevenxuguang The duplicate explains how to solve NPE in general - if you try to understand how it you will find that fixing your problem is easy...

Comment: Ok..................But I cannot delete the post and why my points get deducted so much......................

Answer (score -1, accepted):

where is `childNodes` initiated?

```
root.childNodes.add(n1);  Line 1
```

must throw a `NPE`.

add this in your `Node` class and it will work:

```
List<Node> childNodes = new ArrayList<>();
```

or

```
Node root = new Node(0);
Node n1 = new Node(1);
root.childNodes = new ArrayList();
root.childNodes.add(n1);
```

Comment: Sure, it says that "You can accept that in 10 minutes".

Comment: why the downvote? because I have answered a duplicate?

Comment: @StefanBeike Yes, probably. This is such an obvious duplicate - posting an answer to a question like this is often seen as reputation-grab, which someone decided was worthy for a downvote. On a sidenote, there's no need to get all huffy about it - it's one downvote, you've got plenty of rep to spare.

Comment: not from my point of view. Closing something because it is a duplicate is ok for me. Downvoting a correct answer because of that is not ok.

Comment: Users are free to up- or downvote using any criteria they choose. The ideal is that they base their vote on the content of the answer; the reality is sometimes votes happen for other reasons.

Comment: sure but a lot of answers I saw today were duplicates. nevertheless no reason for downvote. Our opinions are divided. Thats ok...